# Removing annotation from for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, annotations

The problem is that `aux1.remove()` doesn't remove the annotations added to the scatter points.

But `aux.remove()` does remove the scatter points. So in the end I get a lot of annotations when I keep adding / removing new points.

```
aux = plt.scatter(obj_dy[:], obj_dx[:], color='green')

for k in range(len(obj_index)):
    aux1 = plt.annotate(str(obj_index[k]), xy = (obj_dy[k], obj_dx[k]))
plt.pause(0.1000)
aux.remove()
aux1.remove()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the creation of the annotations is inside a for loop. When you do `aux1.remove()` you only remove the last annotation on the axes.

One solution would be to put `aux1` into a list and the after the for loop is finished, loop through the list and remove the annotations:

```
aux = plt.scatter(obj_dy[:], obj_dx[:], color='green')

aux1_list = [] # empty list that the annotation will go in

for k in range(len(obj_index)):
    aux1 = plt.annotate(str(obj_index[k]), xy = (obj_dy[k], obj_dx[k]))
    aux1_list.append(aux1)

plt.pause(0.1)
aux.remove() # remove scatter points

# remove annotations
for ann in aux1_list:
    ann.remove()

plt.pause(0.01) 
plt.show()
```

Another way to do this without having to store the annotation in a list would be to loop through the `axes` children, check whether they are annotations and remove if that is the case:

```
for child in plt.gca().get_children():
    if isinstance(child, matplotlib.text.Annotation):
        child.remove()
```